# Recursion for multiple Hierarchies and summing all parents

Tags: sql-server, recursion

I have just begun diving into SQL Server. Wrote my first script less than a month ago, so I've been on a steep learning curve.

I have an Item List table where there are multiple Hierarchies of various depths.
Here is a sample.

```
--To Get Started, Here are some Samples of a components list of nearly 1000 records
CREATE TABLE [Sampletbl]
(
     ID varchar(20), 
     Months smallint, 
     DirectParent varchar(20), 
     HighestParent varchar(20)
)

INSERT INTO Sampletbl (ID, Months, DirectParent, HighestParent)
VALUES ('BERB CPB06',   11, 'BERB CPB18',   'BERB CPB18'),
       ('BERB CPB08',    9, 'BERB CPB18',   'BERB CPB18'),
       ('BERB CPB18',   10, 'Prop',         'BERB CPB18'),
       ('BUXU GNV06',   12, 'BUXU GNV18',   'BUXU GNV98'),
       ('BUXU GNV08',   10, 'BUXU GNV18',   'BUXU GNV98'),
       ('BUXU GNV10',   11, 'BUXU GNV32',   'BUXU GNV98'),
       ('BUXU GNV18',    9, 'BUXU GNV32',   'BUXU GNV98'),
       ('BUXU GNV32',   11, 'BUXU GNV98',   'BUXU GNV98'),
       ('BUXU GNV98',   12, 'Prop',         'BUXU GNV98'),
       ('HYDR ARANN08', 12, 'Prop',         'HYDR ARANN08'), --This and the record below are original, even though they have the same prefix
       ('HYDR ARANN18', 12, 'Prop',         'HYDR ARANN18')
```

The Items with a direct parent of 'Prop' are originals - they have no parent.
Parents can have multiple children.

Here is a depth chart.

```
with ItemsAndTheirPrecedents (ID, DirectParent, Precedents) As
(
Select  ID,
        DirectParent,
        0
From    Sampletbl
Where   DirectParent = 'Prop'
Union All

Select  Sampletbl.ID,
        Sampletbl.DirectParent,
        ItemsAndTheirPrecedents.Precedents + 1
From    Sampletbl
    Join ItemsAndTheirPrecedents on Sampletbl.DirectParent = ItemsAndTheirPrecedents.ID

)

select *
from ItemsAndTheirPrecedents
Order by Precedents
--If the direct Parent is Prop there are no ancestors - this item starts the tree
```

What I would Like to do is total the Months for each Item and ALL of its parents (if any).

Something Like this:

| ID | Months | Parent | Total Months |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| BERB CPB06 | 11 | BERB CPB18 | 21 |
| BERB CPB08 | 9 | BERB CPB18 | 19 |
| BERB CPB18 | 10 | Prop | 10 |
| BUXU GNV06 | 12 | BUXU GNV18 | 44 |
| BUXU GNV08 | 10 | BUXU GNV18 | 42 |
| BUXU GNV10 | 11 | BUXU GNV32 | 34 |
| BUXU GNV18 | 9 | BUXU GNV32 | 32 |
| BUXU GNV32 | 11 | BUXU GNV98 | 23 |
| BUXU GNV98 | 12 | Prop | 12 |
| HYDR ARANN08 | 12 | Prop | 12 |
| HYDR ARANN18 | 12 | Prop | 12 |

Where in the most complex item, the total keeps adding for each layer:

| ID | Months | Total Months |
| --- | --- | --- |
| BUXU GNV06 | 12 | 44 |
| BUXU GNV18 | 9 | 32 |
| BUXU GNV32 | 11 | 23 |
| BUXU GNV98 | 12 | 12 |

With the following recursion I can get the sum of months for an Item and its direct parent.

```
with TotalMonthsForItemsAndParents (ID, Months, DirectParent, TotalMonths) As
(
Select  ID,
        Months,
        DirectParent,
        Months
From    Sampletbl
Where   DirectParent = 'Prop' 

Union All

Select  Sampletbl.ID,
        Sampletbl.Months,
        Sampletbl.DirectParent,
        TotalMonthsForItemsAndParents.Months + Sampletbl.Months
From    Sampletbl
    Join TotalMonthsForItemsAndParents on Sampletbl.DirectParent = TotalMonthsForItemsAndParents.ID

)

select * 
from TotalMonthsForItemsAndParents
Order by ID
```

But I can't wrap my mind around how to make it look for multiple generations and sum them to the level of each item.

Thank you for helping me. I know the subject of recursive cte's is all over this site, but I couldn't find what I was looking for. I've honestly spent all week on this.

Comment: sorry, that second table works in preview, but not in the post.

Comment: Thanks for fixing that table Marc!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you've written the last query, it's only taking into account the immediately preceding ancestor in the hierarchy. Here's a trick that keeps track of all of the ancestors as you go:

```
with TotalMonthsForItemsAndParents (ID, Months, DirectParent, Months, RunningTotal) As
(
    Select  ID,
            Months,
            DirectParent,
            Months,
            Months as RunningTotal 
    From    Sampletbl
    Where   DirectParent = 'Prop' 

    Union All

    Select  Sampletbl.ID,
            Sampletbl.Months,
            Sampletbl.DirectParent,
            Sampletbl.Months,
            TotalMonthsForItemsAndParents.RunningTotal + Sampletbl.Months
    From    Sampletbl
    Join TotalMonthsForItemsAndParents on Sampletbl.DirectParent = TotalMonthsForItemsAndParents.ID
)

select *
from TotalMonthsForItemsAndParents
Order by ID;
```

For the base case, the RunningTotal value is just that row's Months value. For subsequent (i.e. the recursive step), it's the sum of this level's Months value and the previous level's RunningTotal.

Comment: Thanks! So simple. So the naming convention of the totals column in the first description of the cte is where I went wrong?

Comment: Not quite. I've made a small edit to my answer for clarity. Before, your definition for Total Months was defined as `parent.Months + child.Months`. Here, I'm defining it as `parent.RunningTotal + child.Months`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
;with TotalMonthsForItemsAndParents (
    ID
    , Months
    , DirectParent
    , TotalMonths
    , lvl )
As
(
    -- Anchor member
    Select  ID,
            Months,
            DirectParent,
            Months as TotalMonths,
            lvl = 1
    From    Sampletbl
        
    Union All

     -- Recursive member: the direct parent (if any) of the previous recursion
    Select  Sampletbl.ID,
            Sampletbl.Months,
            Sampletbl.DirectParent,
            TotalMonths = total.TotalMonths + Sampletbl.Months,
            lvl = lvl + 1
    From    Sampletbl 
    Join    TotalMonthsForItemsAndParents as total on Sampletbl.DirectParent = total.ID
)
select ID
        , Months
        , DirectParent
        , TotalMonths
from (
    -- use row_number() so as to keep only the latest recursion 
    select ID
        , Months
        , DirectParent
        , TotalMonths
        , row_number() over (partition by ID order by lvl desc) as rn
    from TotalMonthsForItemsAndParents
) t
where t.rn = 1
Order by ID
```

[Demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/dd40f/1)